# Populate ListView with values from another class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to populate the ListView of to show a specific value, which is going to be title through the data of another class in Android Studio using Kotlin. I know how to populate the ListView, but I am not sure on how to get the "title" value and put it into the ListView
This is an example of what I want it to look:

[image]

Class used to populate the ListView:

```
class SimpleViewListOfMoviesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_list_of_movies)

        val movies = SimpleMovieItem()
        val test = arrayOf(movies.title)

        val listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test)
        movielist.adapter = listAdapter
      }
}
```

Class with the data inside:

```
class SimpleMovieSampleData {



    companion object{

        var simpleMovieitemArray : ArrayList<SimpleMovieItem>
        init {

            simpleMovieitemArray = ArrayList<SimpleMovieItem>()
            populateSimpleMovieItem()
        }



        fun populateSimpleMovieItem() : ArrayList<SimpleMovieItem>{

            simpleMovieitemArray.add(
                SimpleMovieItem("Super-assassin John Wick returns with a \$14 million price tag on his head and an army of bounty-hunting killers on his trail. After killing a member of the shadowy international assassin’s guild, the High Table, John Wick is excommunicado, but the world’s most ruthless hit men and women await his every turn.",
                    "August 23, 2019",
                    "English",
                    "John Wick: Chapter 3 - Parabellum ")
            )

            simpleMovieitemArray.add(
                SimpleMovieItem("After faking his death, a tech billionaire recruits a team of international operatives for a bold and bloody mission to take down a brutal dictator.",
                    "December 13, 2019",
                    "English",
                    "6 Underground ")
            )

            simpleMovieitemArray.add(
                SimpleMovieItem("After fighting his demons for decades, John Rambo now lives in peace on his family ranch in Arizona, but his rest is interrupted when Gabriela, the granddaughter of his housekeeper María, disappears after crossing the border into Mexico to meet her biological father. Rambo, who has become a true father figure for Gabriela over the years, undertakes a desperate and dangerous journey to find her.",
                    "December 17, 2019",
                    "English",
                    "Rambo: Last Blood ")
            )
return simpleMovieitemArray
        }

    }
}
```

SimpleMovieItem

```
package com.nyp.sit.movieviewerbasic_starter

class SimpleMovieItem(
    var overview: String? = null,
    var release_date: String? = null, var original_langauge: String? = null,
    var title: String? = null
) {


    init {

        this.overview = overview
        this.release_date = release_date
        this.original_langauge = original_langauge
        this.title = title

    }


}
```

Comment: Kindly try to elaborate by putting more information on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map through the `movies` array and map their titles:

```
val movies = SimpleMovieSampleData.simpleMovieitemArray
val moviesTitles = movies.map { it.title }.toTypedArray()

val listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, moviesTitles)
movielist.adapter = listAdapter
```

If you need to display a toast message with the title of a clicked movie you can use the `setOnItemClickListener` method:

```
movielist.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> 
    val movieTitle = listAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position)
    Toast.makeText(this@ SimpleViewListOfMoviesActivity, movieTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: that is kind of what i need, but what i want is each movie title spilt into each line, as I want to try using Toast to display the title of each movie, like the image above. Removing "arrayOf" should fix that right?

Comment: Try to use the `toTypedArray()` function to transform the list into an array. If you want to use a Toast you will need to transform the list into a string. What message do you want to show?

Comment: I just want to display the title of the movie when i click on it as a test.